# How to get a list of Uris that were granted permissions with context.grantUriPermission()?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is it possible to get a list of Uris\Packages that were granted permissions with

```
context.grantUriPermission(String toPackage, Uri uri, int modeFlags);
```

I can't find corresponding methods in the documentation for [Context](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html).
The docs has only grantUriPermission(), revokeUriPermission() and checkUriPermission() methods that are related to permissions.

Do I need to create some data structure for Uris that were granted permissions and maintain it manually or there is some way to get them from the system?